# Why does this evaluate to false in VB.Net?

Tags: .net, sql, vb.net

I have this code and it evaluates to false instead of a string. All its doing is building a string. Any ideas why?

```
 Dim statement As String = "Insert into table dbo.IV00101 values(" +
        "ITEMNMBR=" + "@ITEMNMBR" + "," +
        "ITEMDESC=" + "@ITEMDESC" + " , " +
        "NOTEINDX=" + "@NOTEINDX" + "," +
        "ITMSHNAM=" + DBNull.Value + "," +
        "ITEMTYPE=" + "1" + "," +
        "STNDCOST=" + "@STNDCOST" + "," +
        "CURRCOST=" + "@CURRCOST" + "," +
        "ITEMSHWT=" + "0" + "," +
        "DECPLQTY=" + "3" + "," +
        "DECPLCUR=" + "3" + "," +
        "ITMTSHID=" + DBNull.Value + "," +
        "TAXOPTNS=" + "1" + "," +
        "IVIVINDX=" + "0" + "," +
        "IVIVOFIX=" + "0" + "," +
        "IVCOGSIX=" + "0" + "," +
        "IVSLSIDX=" + "0" + "," +
        "IVSLDSIX=" + "0" + "," +
        "IVSLRNIX=" + "0" + "," +
        "IVINUSIX=" + "0" + "," +
        "IVINSVIX=" + "0" + "," +
        "IVDMGIDX=" + "0" + "," +
        "IVVARIDX=" + "0" + "," +
        "DPSHPIDX=" + "0" + "," +
        "PURPVIDX=" + "0" + "," +
        "UPPVIDX=" + "0" + "," +
        "IVRETIDX" + "0" + "," +
        "ASMVRIDX=" + "0" + "," +
        "ITMCLSCD=" + DBNull.Value + "," +
        "ITMTRKOP=" + "1" + "," +
        "LOTTYPEAC=" + DBNull.Value + "," +
        "KPERHIST=" + "0" + "," +
        "KPTRXHST=" + "0" + "," +
        "KPCALHST=" + "0" + "," +
        "KPDSTHST=" + "0" + "," +
        "ALWBKORD=" + "0" + "," +
        "VCTNMTHD=" + "1" + "," +
        "UOMSCHDL=" + "@UOMSCHDL" + "," +
        "ALTITEM1=" + DBNull.Value + "," +
        "ALTITEM2=" + DBNull.Value + "," +
        "USCATVLS_1=" + DBNull.Value + "," +
        "USCATVLS_2=" + DBNull.Value + "," +
        "USCATVLS_3=" + DBNull.Value + "," +
        "USCATVLS_5=" + DBNull.Value + "," +
        "USCATVLS_4=" + DBNull.Value + "," +
        "USCATVLS_6=" + DBNull.Value + "," +
        "MSTRCDTY=" + "1" + "," +
        "MODIFDT=" + Date.Today.ToString() + "," +
        "CREATDDT=" + Date.Today.ToString() + "," +
        "WRNTYDYS=" + "0" + "," +
        "PRCLEVEL=" + DBNull.Value + "," +
        "LOCNCODE=" + DBNull.Value + "," +
        "PINFLIDX=" + "0" + "," +
        "PURMCIDX=" + "0" + "," +
        "IVINFIDX=" + "0" + "," +
        "INVMCIDX=" + "0" + "," +
        "CGSINFLX=" + "0" + "," +
        "CGSMCIDX=" + "0" + "," +
        "ITEMCODE=" + DBNull.Value + "," +
        "TCC=" + DBNull.Value + "," +
        "PriceGroup=" + DBNull.Value + "," +
        "PRICMTHD=" + "1" + "," +
        "PRCHSUOM=" + DBNull.Value + "," +
        "SELNGUOM=" + DBNull.Value + "," +
        "KTACCTSR=" + "0" + "," +
        "LASTGENSN=" = DBNull.Value + "," +
        "ABCCODE=" + "1" + "," +
        "Revalue_Inventory=" + "1" + "," +
        "Tolerance_Percentage=" + "0" + "," +
        "Purchase_Item_Tax_Schedu=" + DBNull.Value + "," +
        "Purchase_Tax_Options=" + "1" + "," +
        "ITMPLNNNGTYP=" + "1" + "," +
        "STTSTCLVLPRCNTG=" + "0" + "," +
        "CNTRYORGN=" + DBNull.Value + "," +
        "INACTIVE=" + "0" + "," +
        "MINSHELF1=" + "0" + "," +
        "MINSHELF2=" + "0" + "," +
        "INCLUDEINDP=" + "0" + "," +
        "LOTEXPWARN=" + "0" + "," +
        "LOTEXPWARNDAYS=" + "0" + "," +
        "LASTGENLOT=" + DBNull.Value + "," +
        "Lot_Split_Quantity=" + "0.00000" + "," +
        "DEX_ROW_TS=" + Date.Today.ToString() + "," +
        "DEX_RoW_ID=" + "@DEX_RoW_ID" +
        ")"
```

Comment: Where did all the old comments go?

Comment: The fact that there's an issue with this "line" is a good indication that a string building loop would be a better implementation.  As @dlev discovered, just one of the **249** plus symbols was in error.  A loop would only have four plus symbols max, and this kind of error would show up immediately.

Comment: When concatenating strings in visual basic, it is always better to use the & operator instead of +.  The + operator has a complex set of rules to determine whether to add, concatenate, or throw an error.  The & operator is only for string operands and always widens its operands to String.

Comment: @Hand-E-Food and briddums : Thanks for the insight. I will move towards a cleaner way of doing this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As I mentioned in comment, you have a typo in your string concatentations:

```
"KTACCTSR=" + "0" + "," +
"LASTGENSN=" ***=*** DBNull.Value + "," +
"ABCCODE=" + "1" + "," +
```

Changing that to a `+` should get you going again.

With the `=` in place, it was just comparing the two strings for equality (which of course is `false`) and then converting *that* result into the string `"False"`.

There a couple ways to avoid this kind of snafu in the future. One is to put `Option Strict On` at the top of the file, which will warn you about this kind of thing. Another would be use smaller, more manageable string chunks, so that each one has a lower probability of being the problem.

In terms of debugging something like this, I compiled the code, then opened it using ILSpy. It showed the code being generated (i.e. the string compare) as well as which strings were actually being compared. Seeing that made it easy to locate the offending `=` (since it appeared right after the end of the first argument to the string comparison.)

Comment: Well spotted in a terrible mess. +1.